# Flask import error and Anaconda

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, anaconda

I am having trouble running a `Flask` script. I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sample.py", line 17, in <module>
    from flask import Flask, make_response, render_template, request
ImportError: No module named flask
```

The thing is I am under Windows currently and `flask` is installed with `pip install Flask`. I am assuming the `ImportError: No module named flask` it's because the module is installed in the `C:\User\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages` directory and thus cannot be found by the Python interpreter:

```
Python 2.7.8 (default, Jun 30 2014, 16:03:49) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win 32
```

Any suggestions on how to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using conda to install flask: `conda install flask`

Answer (score 0):

Do you have multiple versions of Python installed?

Commonly there's a system Python, then a local Python -- if a module is installed in #1, it won't be visible in #2.

Consider using `virtualenvwrapper` -- it helps with custom Pythons and modules. http://blog.fruiapps.com/2012/06/An-introductory-tutorial-to-python-virtualenv-and-virtualenvwrapper